# How can we expose HikariCp.connection.timeout metrics as Gauge and not counter which is by default exposed?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hikaricp, micrometer

I can see in the HikariCP MicrometerMetricsTracker class that hikaricp.connections.timeout metrics are exposed as counter metrics.

```
  this.connectionTimeoutCounter = Counter.builder(METRIC_NAME_TIMEOUT_RATE)
     .description("Connection timeout total count")
     .tags(METRIC_CATEGORY, poolName)
     .register(meterRegistry);
```

This by default is exposing the metrics as count which is keep on incrementing. I need to use it as a gauge metric which can give dynamic/live values that should be measured directly and not the total incrementing count. Is there any way we can do it? I am trying something like this but here I don't have the information on connection timeout:

```
    Gauge.builder("my.custom.metric.gauge", () -> "need info of timeout")
            .register(meterRegistry);
```

Answer (score 1):

`connectionTimeoutCounter` tells you how many times a timeout happened. This is by definition a Counter. Depending on you backend this can be a cumulative (since the star of the app) value or a delta value (since the previous publish). If you are using a backend (i.e.: Prometheus) that uses cumulative counters, they should also offer some sort of a `rate` function which should tell you how many timeout did happen in the time window you choose.